# Why is my switch case only returning once?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am creating an application where you can make a hamburger. Only problem is when I press, for example: Add salad, it will add the div with className Salad only once. I can't add Salad twice.

I've tried to add an key to the div so that the div's will be different but the key element will increase only with one and it won't give me more 's.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../Hamburger/Hamburger.css';

class Hamburger extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.render();
    }

    renderSwitch(aantal, type) {

        if (aantal === 0) {
            return null;
        }

        let ingredient = null;

        switch (type) {
            case ("salad"):
                ingredient = <div className="Salad">rr</div>;
                break;
            case ("bacon"):
                ingredient = <div className="Bacon">rr</div>;
                break;
            case ("cheese"):
                ingredient = <div className="Cheese">rr</div>;
                break;
            case ("meat"):
                ingredient = <div className="Meat">rr</div>;
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }

        return ingredient;

    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div style={style}>
                <div style={{ color: "transparent" }}>f</div>
                <div className="BreadTop">r</div>
```

This refers from the original state, see state below

```
{this.props.artikelen.map(ctrl => (
                    this.renderSwitch(ctrl.aantal, ctrl.type)
                ))}


                <div className="BreadBottom">r</div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Hamburger



{* THIS.PROPS.ARTIKELEN = *}

state = {
        artikelen: [
            { naam: 'Salad', type: 'salad', aantal: 0 },
            { naam: 'Bacon', type: 'bacon', aantal: 0 },
            { naam: 'Cheese', type: 'cheese', aantal: 0 },
            { naam: 'Meat', type: 'meat', aantal: 0 },
        ]
    }
```

I expect (2 clicks on add Salad):

```
<div className="Salad"></div>
<div className="Salad"></div>
```

But it will only give me:

```
<div className="Salad"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically return an array of elements on the render function.
I think that you can also remove this part of code from componentDidUpdate, since the render function will trigger automatically when the component is called.

```
this.render();
```

Change your renderSwitch function to something like this:

```
renderSwitch() {
    let ingredient = [];

    this.props.artikelen.forEach(function(ctrl) {

        if (ctrl.aantal === 0) {
            continue;
        }

        switch (ctrl.type) {
            case ("salad"):
                ingredient.push(<div className="Salad">rr</div>);
                break;
            case ("bacon"):
                ingredient.push(<div className="Bacon">rr</div>);
                break;
            case ("cheese"):
                ingredient.push(<div className="Cheese">rr</div>);
                break;
            case ("meat"):
                ingredient.push(<div className="Meat">rr</div>);
                break;
            default:
            ;
       }
    });


    return (<div>
        {ingredient}
    </div>);

}
```

And then change this code:

```
{this.props.artikelen.map(ctrl => (
                this.renderSwitch(ctrl.aantal, ctrl.type)
            ))}


            <div className="BreadBottom">r</div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

To something like this:

```
            {this.renderSwitch()}
            <div className="BreadBottom">r</div>

        </div>
    )
}
```